# Orderby lambda expression on anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I refactored a linq to entities query to speed it up and broke my orderby lambda feature.

Is there any way to get this to working again since the query is now a join and creating an anonymous type?

**Refactored code that is broken because of the orderBy:**

```
public List<UserProductRating> GetUserProductRatings<TKey>(int userId, IPager pager, Func<UserProductRating, TKey> orderBy)
{
    var result = _userProductRatingRepo.Table.Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
        .Join(_productRepo.Table, outer => outer.ProductId, inner => inner.ProductId,
        (outer, inner) => new { UserProductRating = outer, Product = inner })
        .OrderByDescending(o => orderBy) // won't work because the query creates an anonymous type above that doesn't match the Func<> definition
        .Skip(pager.Skip).Take(pager.PageSize)
        .Select(a => new
        {
            a.UserProductRating.UserId,
            a.UserProductRating.ProductId,
            a.UserProductRating.VoteCount,
            a.UserProductRating.TotalViews,
            a.UserProductRating.Rating,
            a.Product.Name
        }).ToList();
}
```

**Old code that works with orderBy:**

```
public List<UserProductRating> GetUserProductRatings<TKey>(int userId, IPager pager, Func<UserProductRating, TKey> orderBy)
{
    return _userProductRatingRepo.Table
                .Include(a => a.Product)
                .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
                .OrderByDescending(orderBy)
                .Skip(pager.Skip)
                .Take(pager.PageSize)
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: try moving the orderby before doing the join

Comment: unfortunately that selects every row in the database with no where clause and no join either for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `OrderBy` parameter takes a `UserProductRating` and you include it as one of the anonymous type's properties, you should be able to do this:

```
public List<UserProductRating> GetUserProductRatings<TKey>(int userId, IPager pager, Func<UserProductRating, TKey> orderBy)
{
    var result = _userProductRatingRepo.Table.Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
        .Join(_productRepo.Table, outer => outer.ProductId, inner => inner.ProductId,
        (outer, inner) => new { UserProductRating = outer, Product = inner })
        .OrderByDescending(o => orderBy(o.UserProductRating)) // <-- pass the joined property to the order function 
        .Skip(pager.Skip).Take(pager.PageSize)
        .Select(a => new
        {
            a.UserProductRating.UserId,
            a.UserProductRating.ProductId,
            a.UserProductRating.VoteCount,
            a.UserProductRating.TotalViews,
            a.UserProductRating.Rating,
            a.Product.Name
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It throws `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`. Also changed it to `Expression<Func<UserProductRating, TKey>> orderBy` but that throws `The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: any other suggestions on this?